# Deshabilitar ripple loading para utilizar solo skeleton en primeng tabla

Tags: table, primeng, skeleton

Quiero utilizar [skeleton](https://www.primefaces.org/primeng/skeleton) para la espera de la carga de la tabla, pero cuando pongo el [loading]="idLoading" se ponen los dos, el skeleton y el ripple, como desactivo el ripple para dejar solo el skeleton?, o hya otra forma mejor de hacerlo?, hasta ahorita llevo esto

```
<p-table #dt [value]="data" [rows]="10" [rowHover]="true" [showCurrentPageReport]="true" [rowsPerPageOptions]="[10,25,50]" [paginator]="true" 
    responsiveLayout="scroll" currentPageReportTemplate="Mostrando {first} a {last} de {totalRecords}" [filterDelay]="0"
    [globalFilterFields]="['name']" [loading]="idLoading" id="depTable">
    
    <ng-template pTemplate="header">
      <tr>
        <th pSortableColumn="col1">col1 <p-sortIcon field="col1"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="col2">col2 <p-sortIcon field="col2"></p-sortIcon></th>
        <th pSortableColumn="col3">col3 <p-sortIcon field="col3"></p-sortIcon></th>
      </tr>          
    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="body" let-department>
      
      <tr>
        <td>{{ info.col1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ info.col2 }}</td>
        <td>{{ info.col3 }}</td>
      </tr>

    </ng-template>

    <ng-template pTemplate="loadingbody">
      <tr><td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td><td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td><td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td></tr>
      <tr><td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td><td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td><td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td></tr>
      <tr><td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td><td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td><td><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td></tr>
    </ng-template>
    
  </p-table>
```

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Te recomiendo usar el efecto de *skeleton* en el pTemplate body sin necesidad de crear una directiva (loadingbody).

Atendiendo que *idLoading* es un **boolean** donde *true* significa sin datos (todavía) podrías usar lo siguiente.

```
<ng-template pTemplate="body" let-department>
    <tr *ngIf="idLoading">
        <td *ngFor="let i of [].constructor(3);"><p-skeleton></p-skeleton></td>
    </tr>
    <tr *ngIf="!idLoading">
        <td>{{ department.col1 }}</td>
        <td>{{ department.col2 }}</td>
        <td>{{ department.col3 }}</td>
    </tr>

</ng-template>
```